# Disable layer touch in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Adding another uppper layer in cocos2d still touchable background layer. How to disable background layer just like pause screen. Here is how i am trying to do:

```
GamePauseLayer *pGamePauseLayer = [GamePauseLayer node];
[self addChild:pGamePauseLayer z:50];
```

z is higher than previous layer and other UI components. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: touch priority is not related to z order.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help. In your `GamePauseLayer`'s `onEnter` method write the following:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:257 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

and in `onExit`:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
```

Comment: this will not prevent touches to be passed to the "underlying" menu items. Touch priority is not related to z order.  At same priority, the touches are passed in the reverse order they were added to the touchDispatcher. Menu items default priority to be processed before any '0' priority object.

Comment: Actually i thought that swallowTouches:YES would help

Comment: menu items default to a touch priority that is higher (-256) than others. To convince yourself, do a quick test, add a transparent layer at 0 touch priority, and touch a 'lower' button, it will still get the touch, even if you swallow the touch in the layer. Add the same layer at -257, and the button will not receive the touch. Tricky to play with priorities, not recommending to do this. I believe cocos2d version 3.x helps in regards to touch handling.